# What is meant by PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION?

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I need a clarity about pragma autonomous transaction. I have used a overlap select query in trigger and insert query in procedure. If I import two records in single file, the 2nd record is same as 1st record so the second record should be shown as overlap error. Now the select query in trigger executes but the error is not thrown by using the pragma autonomous transaction.

Answer (score 3):

`AUTONMOUS_TRANSACTION` is a nested transaction. It executes DML independently of the calling transaction. So a query issued in an autonomous transaction won't see any uncommitted changes in the outer transaction. This is why you don't see your error message: the invalid state only exists in the uncommitted changes of the  transaction.

Obviously you are using `AUTONMOUS_TRANSACTION` to avoid a mutating table error. However, a better solution would be to use a COMPOUND DML trigger: use a `FOR EACH ROW` to store the changes in an array, then verify them for no overlaps in the `AFTER` statement stage. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0).